# Image Gallery in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have a multiple upload images, using carrier wave, on my application and with the help of you guys, in another question, I was able to display all the images with a each method. It works very well but I would like to improve it. I want to do a image gallery with a carousel and when the user click at it opens a modal with the image bigger. 

I try to do following the tutorial of W3C School but just doesn't work.
When I try to put the Onclick method the page doesn't render. 


https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp


There is any gem that help me do this? There is any tutorial for a rails application?

I am displaying the images with the following code:

```
<% @imovel.imagens.each do |imagem| %>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <%= image_tag(imagem.url) if @imovel.imagens? %>
          </div>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: See if this help you: http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/

Comment: Yes, it just like that, but how can I do the data toggle and the link of the image, considering that I have just the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will use `link_to` to create the a tag with a block. The arguments are:

`link_to(url, html_options = {})`

Inside the block, you will put the html code inside the a tag (your image).

```
<% @imovel.imagens.each do |imagem| %>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <%= link_to imagem.url, class: 'your-css-class', 'data-toggle': 'lightbox', 'data-gallery': 'name-of-gallery' do %>
                  <%= image_tag(imagem.url) %>
              <% end if @imovel.imagens? %>
          </div>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thiago, thank you so much, It works just fine and the way I need it. The code above doesn't render, because the = signal, I just change for : and works perfect. I can't edit your post because needs to change 6 characters.